# Sql query to join two table for the final output

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

Below are the two tables, customer and department. I am struggling very hard to get the output.

I want to write the query which shows only the department name which have maximum number of employees.

[image]

Answer should be like this ...

[image]

Please help me to write the query.

Comment: What had you done until this?

Comment: We can't help you until you show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a sub-query, and then selecting from that query. With the outer select, you order by the number of employees and then limit it to `1`. This will give you the *top* department, but also has the flexibility to be modified to give you a list of the `x`-number of top departments.

```
SELECT Dep_Name FROM (
    SELECT
        d.Dep_Name, COUNT(*) AS `count`
    FROM
        Departments d
        JOIN Employees e ON e.Dep_id = d.Dep_id
    GROUP BY
        d.Dep_id
) AS q

ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**UPDATE**

Per a comment by @Dems, you can actually handle this *without* a sub-query:

```
SELECT
    d.Dep_Name
FROM
    Departments d
    JOIN Employees e ON e.Dep_id = d.Dep_id
GROUP BY
    d.Dep_id
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks newfurniturey... its working awesome... You solved my problem in a minute... Thank you so much... you are great... :)

Comment: @ShashiRoy No problem! Also, I forgot to mention - if you wanted a *full* list of your departments and their #-of-employees, you can run only the inner-query by itself. Could be useful too =]

Comment: You don't really nned the sub query.  Just put `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1` at the end of what is currently your sub-query.

Comment: @Dems Thanks for the tip; I was overthinking this one. I've updated to include your idea too - thanks again =]

Answer (score 0):

```
            SELECT *
            FROM
            (
                SELECT
                  d.dep_id,
                  d.dep_name,
                  count(c.cus_id) cusCount
                FROM
                  cus c,
                  dep d
                WHERE
                  c.dep_id = d.dep_id
                GROUP BY
                  d.dep_id,d.dep_name
                ORDER BY
                  cusCount desc)
            WHERE
              ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created cus  & dep tables in Oracle 10g database and tested my code successfully.
What database are you using, and could you post you code.
There error message shows that your "Order by" clause is wrong.